# dare I say (it)

Tags: idioms, subject-verb-inversion, auxiliary-verbs, semi-modals

> used when you are saying something that you think other people may not
> like
> *This famous novel is a little, dare I say it, dull.* https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dare-i-say-it

Is this a conditional inversion of auxiliary and subject, as in *had I (not) known* ?

Comment: *Dare I say* is asking for permission, like *May I* or *Do I dare*?

Comment: Yes, this use of _dare_ is semi-modal. May I go? /  Can you come? ?  Dare I say it? /  Need I stay? /  Ought I to speak? ... Modals and semi-modals invert to form **interrogatives** (as here). 'Dare I say it(?)' is obviously a parenthetical (and including the question mark awkward), a hedging Rhetorical question.